# How to open audio and video tags of html getting from website in android

Tags: android, html, wordpress, audio, video

I have a wordpress website and I'm trying to write an android app for it.I get the json of post from my site from this url:[post](http://honarzendegi.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts)
then I use GSON to get the posts content.This is how I present the posts in my app:

```
  <io.github.meness.Library.HtmlTextView.HtmlTextView
        android:id="@+id/txtAuthorComment"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtAuthorName"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imgAuthorAvatarPic"
        android:lineSpacingExtra="2dp"
        android:text="@string/text1"
        android:textSize="12sp"/>
```

This works great,But my real problem is when the post contains audio files or video files,In this case this library doesn't work. Unfortunately I couldn't find any html viewer library that supports the html audio tag for instance.I used **webview** instead but I had many problems with the type face and didn't have much control.Is there any way I Could solve this problem?
Here is a sample tag:

```
<audio src="http://theartofliving.ir/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/Inspiring.mp3" controls="controls"> </audio>
```

Thanks

Comment: show an example of the tag

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko added to the question

Comment: parse `src` from it, and play it with MediaPlayer, for example

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko firstly can you explain how can I do this?and secondly then the audio or video files would be not be in the right place of the post,because I have to add it manually in the layout of the post.If you could explain some more it would be great.thanks a lot

Comment: `how can I do this` try to search yourself first. It's quite easy to find how to parse HTML. ` files would be not be in the right place of the post` yes, because, as you said - `HtmlTextView` does not support them. As alternative, you can add support of them to `HtmlTextView` yourself, or ask the owner to do that.